# Here I am sharing response of API Using Laravel in which i want to specialization name in 'doctor_detail_data' array instead of 'doctor_requests'

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

Here I am sharing response of API where i want to show to show specialization name in 'doctor_detail_data' array instead of "doctor_requests" array. In laravel using foreach loop . Below is my code:

```php
$data['doctor_requests'] = DoctorRequests::where('caretaker_id', $caretaker_id)
    ->whereIn('status', $whereInArray)
    ->with('doctorUserData')->with('doctorDetailData')->get();


foreach ($data['doctor_requests'] as $key => $value) {
    
    $data['doctor_requests'][$key]['specialization'] = Helpers::getSpecialisationName($value['doctorDetailData']['specialization']);
}
return ['code' => 200, 'status' => 'success', 'data' => $data, 'message' => 'Record fetched successfully.'];
```

Response :

```json
    {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "data": {
            "doctor_requests": [
                {
                    "id": 142,
                    "doctor_id": 432,
                    "caretaker_id": 429,
                    "patient_id": 433,
                    "specialization": "Oncology (Cancer Care)",
                    "doctor_user_data": {
                        "id": 432,
                        "name": "Sandeep Singh",
                    },
                  "doctor_detail_data": {
                        "id": 50,
                        "user_id": 432,,
                        "specialization": "3",
                    }
              
            ]
        },
        "message": "Record fetched successfully."
    }
```

Comment: its not clear, you want to modify the request?   so could you show the result you want?

Comment: i want to show specialization name in "doctor_detail_data": {
                        "id": 50,
                        "user_id": 432,,
                        "specialization": "3",
                    }  instead of  "doctor_requests": [
               "doctor_requests" {
                    "id": 142,
                    "specialization": "Oncology (Cancer Care)",

Comment: {
    "status": "error",
    "code": 502,
    "message": "Indirect modification of overloaded element} showing this error

Comment: "specialization": {
                        "code": "500",
                        "message": "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"
                    }, now showing this

Comment: what is code ? for this error

Comment: $data['doctor_requests'][$key]['doctorDetailData']['specialization'] = Helpers::getSpecialisationName($value['doctorDetailData']['specialization']);
                    }

Comment: add that key inside `doctorDetailData` model so you don't need to modify here

Comment: already add public function doctorDetailData(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\DoctorsModal', 'user_id', 'doctor_id');
    }

Comment: no inside that model add `specialization` to name

Comment: same getting error

Comment: Can you share your database structure? From what I can infer from this question (which is not a lot) it looks like it's not well structured